# How come griddedInterpolant works with inputs that should be rejected?

Tags: matlab, interpolation, polynomial-math, polynomials, undocumented-behavior

The documentation of [`griddedInterpolant`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddedinterpolant.html#bvh2cy0-Method) states that the `pchip` method "requires at least 4 (grid) points". However when I run it with 2-point vectors it goes like this:

```
>> F = griddedInterpolant([0,1],[1,2],'pchip')

F = 

  griddedInterpolant with properties:

            GridVectors: {[0 1]}
                 Values: [1 2]
                 Method: 'pchip'
    ExtrapolationMethod: 'pchip'
```

Notice that the method is still `pchip`.

This is very confusing. Why doesn't it throw an error?

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that the current behavior is a design choice by TMW that saves trouble for the majority of users by allowing them to "get away" with some edge cases that would likely be resolved using lower order polynomials anyway. As for the documentation - this likely an oversight.

Take a look at the following example:

```
xq = -2:0.1:2;
p = pchip([0,1],[1,2], xq);
figure(); plot(xq, p);
```

This runs without problem and produces:

[image: Result of example code]

... which, as we can see, degenerated into a linear curve. This isn't really a problem, as it seems to respect the [requirements](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pchip.html#bvjbz1m-2) from a shape-preserving piecewise polynomial.

Indeed, if you want it to be **cubic** (i.e. of power 3), it requires 4 data points (but then it's not really "piecewise" as it only has 1 piece).

Comment: I would regard this kind of "get-away" in an educational and scientific application as horrible, since it does not throw an error when there is an edge case, nor even warn the users that what they see is not what they have asked for, especially when they do not talk about the coercing behavior in the official manual. Eg a student learning interpolation who never refers to other sources would think "when pchip takes less than 4 points the result is the same as linear" rather than "pchip will break when it takes less than 4 points"

Comment: @Yvon or it teaches you not to do things blindly, but instead always be aware of what the code you use does.